# How to set up a two-tier CA hierarchy in Windows 2012R2 certificate authority?

Tags: certificate-authority, windows-server

My apologies if the answer is everywhere but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. My goal is to sign the CSR with an intermediate ca then root ca. So it looks like this.

```
Server_cert > Intermediate CA > Root CA
```

How do I set this up in Windows 2012R2 certification Authority? The only tutorial that I see is it will be signed by a root CA like this.

```
Server_cert > Root CA
```

Comment: "sign the CSR with an intermediate ca then root ca" - Is that just bad phrasing, or is it actually a misunderstanding? The root signs the intermediate cert and the intermediate signs the server cert. The root isn't used to directly sign server certificates in this setup.

Answer (score 1):

AskDS team (Microsoft) have a series of posts that covers 2-tier PKI (what you are looking for) deployment with ADCS:

1. [Part I Design and Planning](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/09/01/designing-and-implementing-a-pki-part-i-design-and-planning.aspx)
2. [Part II Implementation Phases and Certificate Authority Installation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/10/13/designing-and-implementing-a-pki-part-ii.aspx)
3. [Part III Certificate Templates](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/05/27/designing-and-implementing-a-pki-part-iii-certificate-templates.aspx)
4. [Part IV Configuring SSL for Web Enrollment and Enabling Key Archival](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2011/04/06/designing-and-implementing-a-pki-part-iv-configuring-ssl-for-web-enrollment-and-enabling-key-archival.aspx)
5. [Part V Disaster Recovery](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2011/04/07/designing-and-implementing-a-pki-part-v-disaster-recovery.aspx)

what you can safely skip is web enrollment component installtion and key archival feature. Web enrollment is deadly obsolete and key archival is necessary only for user encryption certificates. For SSL/TLS it is not necessary.